Best way to get decent performance with many screens with react-navigation?
My app uses a react-navigation bottom tab navigator, where each tab is a stack navigator - pretty standard stuff.
One of the tabs contains a list of recent notifications, and I want this to work like the Facebook app does: Pressing a notification navigates to the correct screen for it inside the notifications tab - it just slides in from the right.
So even if the screen normally belongs to one of the other tabs, if must also be present in the notifications navigator, so that the user can simply "navigate right" to any screen from the list of notifications. If that screen contains navigational links to other screens, they must also work inside the notifications tab. Pressing back should eventually take the user back to the notifications list (the top-level screen in the notifications tab).
My solution to this has been to define the screens for each tab in a separate module, and then load all these modules in the notifications navigator, so that I can combine them into one giant navigator containing all the screens in the entire app. This has worked quite well, functionally speaking.
However, as the number of screens in my app has grown (190 and counting), I have noticed that switching tabs has become increasingly slow. It now takes 1-2 seconds to simply switch from one tab to another on my iOS simulator. But, importantly, it only becomes this slow after having opened the notifications tab at least once. If I avoid clicking on the notifications tab, performance is acceptable.
Is there a solution to this problem? I have tried enabling freezeOnBlur on all screens, but could not notice any difference.
The ideal solution would be for the notifications tab to load its screens on demand, somehow, but I’m not sure how to achieve something like that.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
